# Java - act as a middleman for file upload to S3

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out the simplest method for allowing clients to upload media (photos and video) to my S3 bucket, without giving them direct access, or using pre-signed URLs.

The idea is that I don't want any kind of media processing to occur, the only thing that I am interested in is to shield the S3 bucket from direct contact with the clients, and record information about the files being uploaded (such as size, type etc.).

Do you have any ideas on how this architecture might be implemeted in a simple way?

Comment: And what are the "clients" here?

Comment: And yes, I have an idea -- in fact it is a project I will be working on  in a few days' time: a `FileSystem` implementation over S3; I already have a [working implementation over DropBox](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox).

Comment: Why do you want to 'shield' S3? Are you concerned about introducing a security hole? With a proper policy, you allow users to upload, without exposing any other files. Solution may depend on what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: The clients are a javascript app and mobile apps. I think I didn't express myself correctly. The "shielding" part is not for security, I simply want to be able to reliably record data about a file, such as knowing who uploaded it, its size and so on. By giving clients access directly to S3, I can't know who uploaded file X or Y, right? ( users may sign up for free with email, using IAM is not feasible )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Uploading from a mobile app

To upload a file from a mobile application to Amazon S3:

- In your back-end, use the [AWS Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSUseCases.html) to generate temporary credentials
- Pass the credentials to your mobile app
- The mobile app can then call AWS APIs

The temporary credentials can be granted a limited set of permissions (eg upload to a specific bucket and path) and are valid only for a limited duration, up to one hour. This is good security practice because no permanent credentials are kept on the mobile device.

### Uploading from a web page

Use a browser-based upload via an HTML form. This allows a form in an HTML page to **securely upload directly the Amazon S3** -- even to private folders. It uses a signed policy to define the permitted action (eg upload to a specific location, up to a certain file size, using a particular permission set).

The form can be static -- no need to recalculate signatures for every individual file to be uploaded.

See: [Authenticating Requests in Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html)

Comment: Awesome, exactly the functionality I was looking for. Only have to figure out a way for native mobile apps to do this, but thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using a mobile app, the better method would be to generate temporary credentials via Security Token Service (STS) and use the native mobile SDK to upload files to S3. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSUseCases.html

Comment: That looks like a better solution, reading its docs right now. Thanks again !